# javascript document.cookie missing some pairs

Tags: javascript, cookies

My script set up ten cookies and the browser successfully saved them, but `document.cookie` only retrieves nine pairs, the missing pair is as follow:

```
auth:4ae9Mq1j6tjt7dV6kV6A0piHB6NnNjijBmecax9mA8cfDpSs6pnAcD7H1%2FUqWMIIB%2BbgtKIJ2w1L2GnXkgV2
```

What happened? Is there a character limit in `document.cookie`? The cookie domain is the same as all the others.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that the server side is sending the cookies with the HttpOnly setting as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie

Cookies sent this way are not accessible thru document.cookie. This is generally used to help protect the cookie value against possible XSS attacks on your site.

You didn't mention which technology you're using on the server side to set the cookies. In case you're using PHP, this link lists the possible ways the HttpOnly flag could be set:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Using_PHP_to_set_HttpOnly

Answer (score 0):

I have two clarifying questions:

1. Why do you think that your "browser successfully saved" all of your cookie crumbs if the final crumb does not appear to be stored in document.cookie?
2. Is the missing value the one you attempted to add last?  If so, from the information you've provided, I assume that value is too long to store in the cookie.

The size in bytes of your cookie crumb string depends on your encoding.

You can read more about the maximum cookie size and number allowed per domain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key).  You can read an older discussion of what happens if you exceed the limit in different browsers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083291/what-is-the-number-and-size-of-cookies-allowed-by-major-browsers).  These limits vary per browser.

[RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) states that browsers should support a cookie size of at least 4096 bytes, at least 300 total cookies, and at least 20 cookies per domain or unique host.  [This article](http://manicode.blogspot.com/2009/08/real-world-cookie-length-limits.html) shows a cookie-size test from 2009.  [This 2008 blog post](http://ajaxian.com/archives/browser-cookie-restriction-research) notes a few more items about how individual browsers handle cookies.

Note that [IE 7 and later](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941495) limit the number of cookies per domain to 50, whereas earlier versions of IE had a limit of 20 per domain.

RFC 2109 and numerous online references suggest that a maximum size of around 4096 bytes is a good general assumption to stick to.  If you can't keep below that limit, you will probably have to store your data on the server somehow.

If it's not cookie size that's the issue, more info on exactly how you're storing and retrieving your cookie values will help the group address your question.

Comment: Did not realize that this thread was so stale when I answered it.  In any case, I hope this answer helps someone.