# What is the cookie size limitation for IE9 and IE 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I know that for IE 8 following RFC 2109 it is 4kb. Is it the same for IE 9 and IE 10?

Comment: On a side note, how much information do you really need to put into your cookies?  *Is there [another way to approach](http://wonko.com/post/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-cookies-to-store-session-data) this sort of thing?* :)

Comment: If you have to ask you're doing something wrong. Remember that the entire cookie data is transmitted in both directions for every single http request. So if you've got 4kb in you cookie and you load a page with fifteen images, four CSS and five JS files (which is not un-reasonable), that's 100kb of extra baggage you're transmitting. That's going to have a noticeable impact on your site performance. If you're thinking of having even bigger cookies than that, the effect will multiply. You're much better off using local storage or server sessions for most things. Cookies are best used sparingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related questions:

- [What are the current cookie limits in modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381526/what-are-the-current-cookie-limits-in-modern-browsers)
- [What is the number and size of cookies allowed by major browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083291/what-is-the-number-and-size-of-cookies-allowed-by-major-browsers?rq=1)

---

## IE10

Max size per cookie: 5117 chars

Max size per domain: 10234 chars

## IE 9

(info missing)

---

According to this site (http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/) ([mirror here](http://www.ruslog.com/tools/cookies.html)) IE8, 9 and 10 behave in the very same way.

In the doubt that this may be outdated, I ran the test with my version of IE (10.0.9200.16580) and got pretty consistent results:

```
17:34:29.657: Starting
17:34:29.706: Max Cookies with Character Length 3 and character "1": 50
17:34:30.776: Max Cookie Character Length using character "1": 5117
17:34:30.854: Max Cookies with Character Length 5117 and character "1": 2
17:34:31.911: Max Cookie Character Length using character "ÿ": 5117
17:34:31.985: Max Cookies with Character Length 5117 and character "ÿ": 2
17:34:32.66: Max Cookies with Character Length 100 and character "1": 50
17:34:32.148: Max Cookies with Character Length 10 and character "1": 50
17:34:32.228: Max Cookies with Character Length 5 and character "1": 50
17:34:32.273: Guessing Max Cookie Count Per Domain: 50
17:34:32.279: Guessing Max Cookie Size Per Cookie: 5117 characters
17:34:32.284: Guessing Max Cookie Size Per Domain: Between 10234 and 15350 characters
17:34:43.479: Starting to get Accurate Max Size Per Domain, may take awhile
17:34:45.539: Max Cookies Size Per Domain: 10234
17:34:45.579: Guessing Max Cookie Size Per Domain: 10234 characters
```

Sources:

- http://www.jstorage.info/
- http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/
- http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/16/browser-cookie-limits/ (no info for IE though)
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/

Comment: appreciate your effort. Would be great if you can elaborate your result. Also the link you have put is broken.

Comment: @change Thanks! I unfortunately have no more info to provide, but just what I found searching around. I'll see if I can get some more other references in the matter to provide more detail. Also, it's weird that you couldn't reach the site -- I tried again today and had no problem.