# How to persist ransack searching parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I'm using [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) for searching users based on their company and active/inactive parameter. This works well when used individually, but I want to make use of both simultaneously. For example, if I select company first and then select active/inactive user, then the company name should persist.

Second, is there a facility in ransack to keep both values persisted when I click back or again on users?

UPDATE :

This is my view:

```
= search_form_for @search, url: search_users_path, method: :post, html: { class: 'sort' } do |f|
  = f.label 'company:'
  = f.select :company_id_eq,
  Company.where('is_inactive = false').collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] },
  {:include_blank => 'All company users'}, :'data-remote' => true, class: 'searchSelect searchUserSelect'

  %div.sort_users
    = f.label 'sort Users:'
    = f.select :deleted_eq,
    [raw("<option value= 0 selected=#{session[:deleted]}>Active Users</option><option value= 1>Inactive Users</option>")],
    {}, :'data-remote' => true, class: 'searchSelect searchUserSelect', style: "width: 205px;"
```

This is my code in controller

```
@search = User.search(params[:q])
@users = @search.result.includes(:company).order("companies.name, last_name").page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

Comment: Is there a nesting issue? `%div.sort_users` should be inside the search form.

Comment: Yes it is in side.. updated

Comment: Why don't you give a concrete example? e.g. these are my records, these are returned given this query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About filters persistence, I'm using the following `before_action`  in `ApplicationController`:

```
def get_query(cookie_key)
  cookies.delete(cookie_key) if params[:clear]
  cookies[cookie_key] = params[:q].to_json if params[:q]
  @query = params[:q].presence || JSON.load(cookies[cookie_key])
end
```

Then, say for an `Intervention` model, I have the following:

```
class InterventionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action only: [:index] do
    get_query('query_interventions')
  end

  def index
    @q = Intervention.search(@query)
    @interventions = @q.result
  end
end
```

That way, if `interventions_path` is called without the `q` param, `cookies['query_interventions']` is checked to access last persisted query. But when `interventions_path` is called with the `q` param, this new query is used and persisted for later use.

Also, if `interventions_path` is called with the `clear` param, the cookie is deleted.

Note this would raise a [`CookieOverflow`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies/CookieOverflow.html) exception if more than 4k are stored, but this is between [1024 and 4096 UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100324/how-many-characters-can-be-stored-in-4kb) and it is usually ok. If not, you should use other kind of session storage.