# How is the max length of a message with GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending notifications over GCM in PHP and I dont know the max length of the message that I can send

Thanks guys!

Comment: have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com) yet?

Comment: yes but it says in kb but I need the lenght in characters

Comment: and also taks about the lenght of the registration id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In UTF-8, characters need between 1 and 4 bytes. So, you can store
>   between 1024 and 4096 UTF-8 characters in 4KB.

See here [How many characters can be stored in 4KB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100324/how-many-characters-can-be-stored-in-4kb)