# fetching cookie whose full name is not known

Tags: javascript, cookies

i am making a web page which stores user input in cookie.
I want to make prediction that means when user presses letter 'a' all cookies starting with 'a' should be fetched .
How can I do that using javascript ?
Actually my web page is intended to be independent of all OS .

Comment: You'll need to parse the `document.cookie` property.

Comment: sorry for my late reply.
i got online now .
i am thinking of creating just one cookie . Is there a limit on its length because i plan to use it to store all vocabulary of user ?

Comment: thank you jay . 
My last comment pertains to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key which will suffice.

Consider this thread solved.

Comment: i arrive at conclusion that - i do not know any way to fetch cookie whose partial name is known. As long as my cookie does not exceed 4KB in size . So far ,USing single will be fine . Tell me if I am wrong ?