# System.Net.CookieException -- ... exceeds the configured maximum size, which is '4096'

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, reporting-services, web-config

I'm working with a custom .Net application with a custom security framework.  Among other things the framework enables user authentication to seamlessly pass to SQL Server Reporting Services for accessing reports in the viewer.  However, I'm getting the following error for certain users:

> 2013-07-03 11:43:00,580 Default.Page_Load(:0) - Initialized
>   ReportServer Url: 'https://www.DOMAIN.com/ReportServer' 2013-07-03
>   11:43:00,696 ReportNavigation.LoadReportCatalog(:0) - Error while
>   accessing the Report Catalog from Web Service Exception:
>   System.Net.CookieException Message: The value size of the cookie is
>   '.ActionSecurity=AAEAAAD_*_*_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...'.
>   This exceeds the configured maximum size, which is '4096'. 
>   Source:
>   System at System.Net.CookieContainer.Add(Cookie cookie, Boolean
>   throwOnError)    at System.Net.CookieContainer.Add(Cookie cookie)
>   at APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportServerProxy.GetCookies()
>   in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportServerProxy.cs:line
>   131    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportServerProxy.GetWebRequest(Uri
>   uri) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportServerProxy.cs:line
>   71    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportingService.ReportingService2005.ListChildren(String
>   Item, Boolean Recursive) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\Web
>   References\ReportingService\Reference.cs:line 871    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportCatalogService.GetCatalogItemList(String
>   path) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportCatalogService.cs:line
>   162    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportCatalogService.GetReportList(String
>   path, Boolean showHidden, String subFolder) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportCatalogService.cs:line
>   116    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportCatalogService.GetReportList(String
>   path, Boolean showHidden) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportCatalogService.cs:line
>   108    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient.ReportCatalogService.GetReportList(String
>   path) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Reporting.WebServiceClient\ReportCatalogService.cs:line
>   81    at ReportNavigation.LoadReportCatalog()
>
> 2013-07-03 11:43:00,749 ASP.global_asax.Application_Error(:0) - An
>   unexpected error has occurred. (URL: /Income Reports/Default.aspx
>   Form Fields:  Exception:
>   System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException Message: Unable to
>   retrieve current HttpContext for this operation. Source:
>   APPNAMEMM.Web.Security    at
>   APPNAMEMM.Web.Security.ActionSecurity.DeleteCookie() in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Web.Security\ActionSecurityProvider\ActionSecurity.cs:line
>   265    at APPNAMEMM.Web.Security.ActionSecurityModule.OnLeave(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\APPNAME\Code\Core\APPNAMEMM.Web.Security\ActionSecurityProvider\ActionSecurityModule.cs:line
>   192    at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnPreSendRequestHeaders()

I've tried altering the web.config in both the app and the ReportServer and ReportManager folder based upon some suggestions including http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits and http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/04/uploading-large-files-in-iis-7.html

However, I'm still getting the error message and users are unable to access the reports.  Is there something else I need to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you set both ?
   http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx
2. However you are getting a CookieException, not a max request limit exception. The above settings have nothing todo with cookies. They refer to file uploads to the server.
3. Seems like are you trying to cram over 4K into a cookie. If so, you can't ..it's a system limit [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key) ..Actually your mileage may vary depending on browser, but if you are setting over 4K in cookies, you probably need to change tactics like switch to sessions.
4. Said yes to N° 3 ? You can correct the error here ..but you'll still probably run into problem N° 3 :-)

Taken from your own stacktrace `This exceeds the configured maximum size, which is '4096' ... at System.Net.CookieContainer.Add(Cookie cookie) ... ReportServerProxy.cs:line 131`

---

```
var container = new System.Net.CookieContainer {
    MaxCookieSize = 8192
};

container.Add(new System.Net.Cookie {
    Value = "somehugevalue"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `localStorage` when the `CookieStore` is limiting.

Code example:

```
localStorage.setItem('ActionSecurity', '[largevalue]');

localStorage.getItem('ActionSecurity');
```

Reference [W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: The contents are not sent to server or not known by server, whereas cookies are. The cookie is used by the framework, not by the OP too.

Comment: The OP is using a custom security framework which communicates seamlessly with the SSRS. He didn't mention details about this custom framework but I assumed it would use the content from the cookie and transfer this information to the SSRS.