# Persist user actions on dojo grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have a dojo enhanced grid on my page with the pagination plug in enabled. 
I like to persist the grid so that say for example the user selects page 3, navigates to another page and then back to the grid page then Page 3 is opened. At the moment it reverts to page one.

Could anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: I think you can store the current page the Paginator has, so when you come back to the page with the grid, tell the Paginator to load that page index.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709142/how-to-save-a-filter-in-dojo)

Comment: thanks xyu, that link helped me out a lot