# Saving a vector to a cookie

Tags: java, javascript, html, cookies, web

I've only found tutorials for saving 1 or 2 values (usually a string). I need to find out how to load an entire vector from a java class into a cookie. would there be any good tutorial sites, examples, list of functions out there that would explain all the little details about cookies?

Assuming you can save an entire vector to a cookie :P

Comment: Cookies are just Strings, if you can stringify your Vector, you can store whatever you want as the value.

Comment: and then just parse the string in javascript later? that seems like a bit of work

Comment: You have set the java and javascript tags but you didn't say how are them involved in your problem. Javascript has it's own local storage now with html 5. You can store much more data there than in a cookie. In order to send the data there you can generate a json object in server and use javascript to save it. Info here http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: that might be what I use. I was hopping to use something other than a stupid cookie (mmmmm cookie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: Don't.

Cookies are meant for small piece of data (like a short string). They aren't meant for arbitrary data storage. [The common limit is 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key).

So if you're 100% sure that your vector is always very short, then you can simply try to convert it into a string representation (a JSON format might be useful).

But if this is for anything but a small personal project, there are dozens of reasons why you shouldn't attempt this (security, for example).