# Unable to set cookie in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to set cookie in js using stringify() with added lib json2.js

```
var data = {
   fields: fields,
   rows: rows,
   data: rows
};
```

Tried like below :

```
$.cookie("instant_view", JSON.stringify(data)); //instant_view as cookie name
```

but could not get any cookie (trying find the cookie name through firefox view cookie info)

also tried for

```
var json_str = JSON.stringify(data);
$.cookie('mycookie', json_str);
```

Still, unable find or set the cookie name.

Comment: should be fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h7Rmb/1/

Comment: perhaps you are attempting to retrieve it on a different path or subdomain of the site? by default, `$.cookie` is going to scope the full  (sub)domain and path unless you specify otherwise

Comment: console.log($.cookie('mycookie')); returns null though

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your cookie does not have the httpOnly flag set, as you will not be able to manipulate it with javascript.

Check your cookies flags for httpOnly.

Comment: Thanks..You are absolutely right, cookies is set httpOnly which is not compatibility for js and i got how to solve the issue .

Comment: No worries. Accepting the answer will help others who stumble across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add [$.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) before using it?

You will get your `cookie data` by using

```
var cookie_data= $.cookie('mycookie');
console.log(cookie_data);
```

Also you need to be careful about your `json-data` it should not be more than `4KB` Read [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)

[Cookie Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/G5VP6/)

**Updated,** you can use [webstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) for storing data more than `4KB` Read [Wiki Web sorage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage) and [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Comment: Is there any way to send cookie more than 4kb? (suppose it may be in 4mb, so what to do)

Comment: there was a issue with httpOnly and now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers.. cookies is set httpOnly which is not compatibility for js and i got how to solve the issue .