# Saving FileList to $.cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I have a FileList like this:

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, File…}
```

I need to remember these files after pages has been refreshed. How can I save them to cookies? (or is there some better methods?) Right now I'm doing it like this `$.cookie("result", files); files = $.cookie("result");` but this gets me [object FileList] which I can't parse. Turning `files` into JSON didn't work either.

Any ideas how can I save the FileList so that I can loop it after page refresh?

EDIT: Maybe I should note that I get the FileList from user input e.g. "Choose files".

Assigning files:

HTML part:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" multiple />
```

JS part:

```
$('#files').on('change', readFiles);
function readFiles(event) {
     var files = event.target.files; //has FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, File…}
     $.cookie.json = true; //converts FileList to json (is correct).
     $.cookie("result", files); //cookie registering also works (atleas with strings) 
     files = $.cookie("result"); //get undefined as a result
     for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsText(f, 'utf-8');
     }
}
```

Comment: Please show some actual code. Your `FileList` example is not javascript.

Comment: @JonathanM: Yes, it is.  That is how a DOM `FileList` object appears in the console.

Comment: @Slaks, ah, I took it as code, not console output.

Comment: @user3960875, when you say you can't "parse" the object FileList, you shouldn't be parsing it. Instead you should just be referencing it, a la `myFileName=files[2];`

Comment: @JonathanM when accessing it as `myFileName=files[2];` I get it in wrong form (as single chars) e.g. `myFileName=files[0];` is `[` not the first file.

Comment: Please update the post to show the code where `files` is getting assigned before the cookie is created.

Comment: @JonathanM Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: I suspect the problem is you're passing `files` to `$.cookie()` as if `files` were a string. It's not. It's an object. Before the first `$.cookie()` call, try encoding `files` as JSON. Throw it up in an alert or to the console and look at the structure to make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: This page says there's an option to automatically convert objects to JSON strings. It's turned on by doing `$.cookie.json=true;`. If you do that, you shouldn't have to json encode before and decode after. It should handle it all for you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1#json

Comment: @JonathanM I tried this before, it encodes to JSON as `{"0":{"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModified":1411305080000,"lastModifiedDate":"2014-09-21T13:11:20.000Z","name":"file2.html","type":"text/html","size":32966}}` but requesting it as `files = $.cookie("result");` gives `undefined` with both suggested methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, in place of:

```
reader.readAsText(f, 'utf-8');
```

you want:

```
reader.readAsText(f.name, 'utf-8');
```

and if you haven't already turned it on, you may need the JSON option, which auto-converts object to JSON strings on storage, and then back to objects on retrieval. It looks like:

```
$.cookie.json=true;
```

Here's the doc: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1#json

NOTE: While the maximum size for each cookie is unlimited according to the [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt), in reality it varies from browser to browser. With 150 files in your list, you're probably hitting the limit, and the `$.cookie` object is rejecting the value. For more info on max sizes, see here: [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)

To avoid this limitation, either divide your list, or use [webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

A better solution would be to store the file list on the server via GET or POST and have the server provide a session cookie that allows retrieval. If using PHP, see [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: When doing `files = event.target.files; $.cookie.json=true; $.cookie("result", files); files = $.cookie("result");` last time I assign `files` from cookies it evaluates to undefined... but when i do `$.cookie("res", "hello"); str = $.cookie("res");` it evaluates correct e.g prints hello. So there's somekind of problem with FileList... is there a limit maybe how long can it be?

Comment: Is the JSON in your comment at the top the exact representation of your FileList? That is, does your list only contain one file? If so, I'm going to run some tests using `{"0":{"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModified":1411305080000,"lastModifiedDate":"‌​2014-09-21T13:11:20.000Z","name":"file2.html","type":"text/html","size":32966}}` as the object.

Comment: This is the exact representation but I have close to 150 files (all lightweight html files <35KB) I get this when I do `var json =JSON.stringify(files);console.log(json);` I expect that `$.cookie.json=true` does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the cookie does the same thing. What is the length of the json string resulting from this `stringify`? Per this answer, the maximum length of the whole cookie is around 4Kb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: Correct it was too big for cookies (32KB). Any other ideas how to remember 32KB JSON after refresh :D?