# Form Authentication asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Does the Form authenticaton in asp.net mvc has a limit size?
=> i have save the roles of my user authentication in my formAuthentication as string with 90 words (Role's name) but when i try to get the data form this formauthentication in my global.asax to custom it as CustomPrincipal the data is emty like the form authentication has not supported this huge of information. any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)