# More lines in one Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

```
$("#fg2").click(function() {
    //Chrome
    var bgColor = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5))';
    //Firefox
    var bgColorff = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%)';
    //Chrome 10+
    var bgColorch = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%)';
    //Opera
    var bgColoro = '-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%)';
    //ie10
    var bgColorie = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%)';

    var fcolor = 'black';

    $.cookie('background', bgColor);
    $.cookie('background', bgColorff);
    $.cookie('background', bgColorch);
    $.cookie('background', bgColoro);
    $.cookie('background', bgColorie);



    $("#nav").css({
        "background": bgColor

    });
        $("#nav ul li a").css({
        "color": fcolor

    });
            $("#mbar h3").css({
        "color": fcolor

    });
            $("#mbar p").css({
        "color": fcolor

    });
    $("#nav").css({
        "background": bgColorff


    });
    $("#nav").css({
        "background": bgColorch


    });
    $("#nav").css({
        "background": bgColoro


    });
    $("#nav").css({
        "background": bgColorie


    });

    $("#mbar").css({
        "background": bgColor


    });
});
```

Now when a user clicks on `fg2` it will change the color (gradient) but it won't save it into a cookie. It only works for Chrome. I want to make gradients and there are more variants to do that for each browser. So I want to add these gradient in one "background".

Comment: Why don't you just read the background value that is set?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `localstorage`, I won't prefer `cookies` until and unless they are created by server.

**SET**

```
localStorage.setItem("background", "#ffffff,#e5e5e5");
```

**GET**

```
function readLS(color)
{
var col = color.split(",");
bgColor = [];
bgColor[0] = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,'+col[0]+'), color-stop(100%,'+col[1]+'));';
bgColor[1] = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, '+col[0]+' 0%, '+col[1]+' 100%);';
bgColor[2] = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, '+col[0]+' 0%,'+col[1]+' 100%);';
bgColor[3] = '-o-linear-gradient(top, '+col[0]+' 0%,'+col[1]+' 100%);';
bgColor[4] = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, '+col[0]+' 0%,'+col[1]+' 100%);';
return bgColor;
}

var opt = readLS(localStorage.getItem("background"));
```

And then use which one you want to use.

Comment: Ok. But how can I use the bgColors? I nver used localstorage. How can i add those bgColors in my div?

Comment: localstorage is no rocket science, It is even much simpler then cookies. `opt` is the array having the codes. `opt[0]` is for `webkit` `opt[1]` for `moz` and so on. So just use them wherever you want.

Comment: I agree that localstorage is the way to go. You could argue how widely supported and persistent it is though.

Comment: I am too dumb to get it :D. How can i change my bg . When i add "background" : opt[1], it wont work.

Comment: What error it is giving? I guess it should work. I checked it in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't suggest using cookies for a use case like this. This is not what cookies are intended to be used for. If you absolutely must use them, and you want to use a more complex data structure, you could [serialize ("stringify") your data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then store it in a cookie:

```
var myCss = {
    'bgColor' : '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5))',
    'bgColorff' : '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%)',
    'fcolor' : 'black'
}

$.cookie('background', JSON.stringify(myCss));
```

Then, at a later instance, you can [parse the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and subsequently re-create the initial object:

```
var stillMyCss = JSON.parse($.cookie('background'));
```

Beware of the [maximum cookie size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key) though.