# Recently Viewed Cookie

Tags: c#, razor, cookies, webmatrix

I'm trying to create a cookie that stores a list of properties that a user views.

I have created a test, and it works in part. Currently, each time i visit a page, it pulls the property ID from the URL and either creates a new string containing that URL, if if a cookie already exists, it'll append that property ID to it.

```
@{
    var rPropertyId = UrlData[0].AsInt(); 

    if(rPropertyId > 0){
        if (Request.Cookies["viewed_properties"] != null){
            var value = Request.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Value.ToString(); 
            var value1 = value + "." + rPropertyId;
            var newcookievalue = String.Join(".", value1.Split(new Char[] {'.'}).Distinct());
            Response.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Value = newcookievalue;
            Response.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1); 
        } else {
            Response.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Value = rPropertyId.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);            
        }
    }  
}

@if (Request.Cookies["viewed_properties"] != null){
    var mylist = Request.Cookies["viewed_properties"].Value.Split(new Char[] {'.'});
    foreach (var i in mylist)
    {
        <p>@i</p>
    }
}
```

What this process doesn't take into consideration, is that if a user visits the same property more than once, i still want only 1 entry of that ID in the cookie. How would i check this, convert it to an array?

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will makes sure you have no duplicates.

Something like:

```
 var newCookieValue = 
        String.Join(".",          
           currentCookieValue.Split(new Char[] {'.'}).Distinct());
```

To add latest to the end - one option is to remove first and add later:

```
 ....
    currentCookieValue.Split(new Char[] {'.'})
       .Where(s => s != newStringValueToAdd)
       .Distinct()
       .ToList()
       .Add(newStringValueToAdd)
```

Side note: cookie values have relatively small length restriction ([What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)), so be careful adding arbitrary number of items to single cookie.

Comment: Ok, so adding the "distinct" function ensures that are no duplicated, which is great. But if it does find a duplicate, it doesn't add the distinct entry to the end of the list?

Comment: for example if i browse property 1, then property 2, then property 3, then property 1 again, i'd expect the "1" to be at the end of the list? is there an overload for this?

Comment: @Gavin5511 there is no overload, you'd have to remove/add it your self (added sample).

Comment: I'm getting: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'. Is there a typo in the "where" clause?