# About session and cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

it is possible to set cookie and session only with username or something like that?

```
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

      setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
```

Comment: @jawed:Yes why not you can set what ever you want in session & cookie

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, **however**;

- I would not store a username in a cookie as it can be modified very easily by the user.

  - For example, if you use `$_COOKIE['username']` in auditing, or within your logic raw, people can "become other people"
- Store the value in your session cookie as the values are stored on your server and only reference by the client with a "random" string.

  - It's harder to pretend to be someone else this way - but not impossible. Ie: Session hijacking (but that's another topic)

Generally, `setcookie` is used to store data on the clients machine that you want to use for when they return at a later date - or example, checking to see if they agreed to your cookie policy.

A session cookie is used for the session of the visit and then destroyed once they leave (ie: logout) the web app.

---

<sup>**Notes**</sup>

- <sup>A client can edit the expiration date of a cookie</sup>
- <sup>Sessions should really have [the secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag)</sup>
- <sup>Sessions should really have [the HttpOnly flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)</sup>
- <sup>There is a [maximum size on cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)</sup>