# Cookies is not setting

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie which is not being set When I var_dump() the variable that I am trying to set in the cookies it shows

```
string(4461) "[" Some string  "]";
```

Does it mean that the size of the string is bigger than the capacity of a COOKIE.

MY php code looks like this

```
setookie('corredores',json_encode(array_unique($corredores))) ;
```

so when I print the cookie it return NULL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Answer (score 1):

Hash your string and then set coocies.
Or serialize it like a array.