# how to pass http error 400 without deleting cookies

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

i have some cookies on my page, and i need to save it and load by page refresh. Saving is working normally, but when i try to refresh. I get "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long", i have 7-8 cookie files in cookies and their summary size is about ~ 18kb.
i need to save an object in cookie its too big, and i split it to array. Then  i write it into cookieStore (it works correct)

```
$scope.cookieDataSavePrepare = function(data) {
            var answerArray = JSON.stringify(data).match(/(.|[\r\n]){1,2048}/g);
            for (var i = 0; i < answerArray.length; i++) {
                $cookieStore.put('dataPart' + i, answerArray[i]);
            }
            $cookieStore.put('dataPartsNumber', answerArray.length);
        };
        $scope.cookieDataLoadPrepare = function() {
            var dataLoad = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $cookieStore.get('dataPartsNumber'); i++) {
                var file = 'dataPart' + i;
                dataLoad.push($cookieStore.get(file));
            };
            return dataLoad.join('');
        };
        $scope.checkData=function() {
            $window.localStorage.setItem('checkData', $scope.cookieDataLoadPrepare());
        }

        $scope.saveTestsToCookieStore = function () {
            $scope.cookieDataSavePrepare($scope.data);
            $cookieStore.put('answeredQuestions',JSON.stringify($scope.answeredTests));
            $cookieStore.put('questionStopped',$scope.currentQN);
        }
```

How can i manage it?

Comment: If you don't need that much cookies on server-side, save them in localStorage? Or even [pouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/). Therefore [the size of all cookies should not exceed 4093 bytes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604212/2308005)

Comment: use localstorage reference link below http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: localstorage is not suitable, i need cookies(

Comment: @inatoff why? Cookies aren't a mechanism for storing large amounts of data, as you already found out.

Comment: If you need data on the client side use localstorage. If you need user or session specific data on the server use a session. If you need data on both ends, either use both, or save it on server and send it to client on each request, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorag. Or [pouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/).
Therefore [50 cookies per domain, and 4093 bytes per domain.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604212/2308005)

### Why?

Max url length is [de facto limit of 2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2308005)
But your data is 18kb is 18000 bytes which exceed 4093 bytes
1 char = 2 bytes, so 18000 / 2 = 9000 chars which exceed max url length