# ASP.NET cookie not written? Redirect issue?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code:

```
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(classes.Member));
                TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, active_resident);

                HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["ActiveUser"];
                if (cookie == null)
                {
                    cookie = new HttpCookie("ActiveUser");
                }

                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                cookie.Value = Genesis.Encryption.EncryptAES(writer.ToString(), Genesis.Generic.ReadAppSettingsValue("GenesisEncryptionKey"));
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                writer.Close();

                // Redirect to Secure Area
                Response.Redirect("secure/dashboard.aspx", false);
```

Strangely, the cookie is not written? However, the ASP.Net Session cookie is? Any ideas?

Comment: Hm seems it has to do with the length of the value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key