# Override the max limit of angular cookie

Tags: json, angularjs

Is there any possibilities to override the max limit of ng-cookies?Im having cookie which size is more than 4KB.Its showing error cookies size is larger then 4KB.Im assigning nested json result to cookie.while retrieving that cookie it is showing  undefined.

Comment: use localStorage instead. Cookies aren't meant for what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/640963/1235298

Actually, RFC 2965, the document that defines how cookies work, specifies that there should be **no maximum length of a cookie's key or value size**, and encourages implementations to support *arbitrarily large* cookies. Each browser's implementation maximum will necessarily be different, so consult individual browser documentation.

See section 5.3, "Implementation Limits", in the RFC [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt).

**So it depends on browsers and not javascript.**