# Flask session is empty after redirect

Tags: python, flask

I have such code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    tmplt = session.get('template', 'No template')
    return render_template('index.html', template=tmplt.decode('utf-8'))


@app.route('/template', methods=['POST'])
def upload_template():
    session['template'] = request.files['template'].read()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '\x0cw1\xd4\xd5\x80%O?q \xcfQrrk\xa3H\xc0[J\xae<\xc3]\xe6\x10\xc0-\xf8S\x08P4[3]PrK\xa9\xf1'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect, that after successful execution of `POST /template`, variable `tmplt` will be equal to what was upload. However, it is empty. Debugging shows that `session['template']` before redirection stores file content, as expected.

Anybody can suggest what's the problem here? Flask docs and googling didn't help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [sessions implementation](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L359), it seems that flask just saves all the session data into the cookie.

And the maximum cookie size, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604212/4612064), is 4KB. If your file is larger than that then browser can just reject the cookie.

In the any case, storing the file into the session doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: so simple... Thanks!

Comment: please how to sole this?

Comment: @hubert if you have the problem above (the session data is too large to be stored in cookie), then you need to change you code in order to make this data smaller - don't store big things into the cookie or use browser local storage to save user data instead of cookie (or both, like having user identity information in the cookie, so you can identify the user on the server and cache user data into the local storage).