# Save full Website in Cookie

Tags: html, cookies

Is it possible to save a whole website in a cookie. For example I have a website with some div´s i can move. And I want to write the text change the size of the div and possition. Is it possble to save the whole  code in a cookie ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A quick search shows a cookie is limited in size: http://stackoverflow.com/q/640938/1909061. Besides that, you can put what you want in there. It's probably *not* what you want though. Google for session and local storage which will point you in a better direction.

Comment: Session storage & local storage would be better to use. I was thinking about those too. It sounds like the only things that need to be cookied are the text + the size + the position's X & Y coordinates. The entire website's HTML markup doesn't need to be cookied, but just those 4 data points for each draggable div which is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Mozilla MDN Notes section on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), it should be possible to do, but it's a VERY, VERY BAD IDEA to do it. Users can have cookies blockers, which will prevent the website from being saved into the cookie.

See the spec at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

> RFC 2965 (Section 5.3, "Implementation Limits") specifies that there
> should be no maximum length of a cookie's key or value size, and
> encourages implementations to support arbitrarily large cookies. Each
> browser's implementation maximum will necessarily be different, so
> consult individual browser documentation.

Here are some links on cookie size limitations:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/f/web-cookies-size-limit.htm
http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/

> If you want to support most browsers, then don't exceed 50 cookies per domain, and don't exceed 4093 bytes per domain (i.e. total size of all cookies <= 4093 bytes)

If you try it & your website's code goes over 4093 bytes, it won't fit! I don't recommend trying it!