# Cookie is not working in MAC -Safari & IOS Mobile- Safari

Tags: c#, cookies, safari

I am creating a model,serializing & assigning into cookie and passing it to next Page.
I am able to get cookie values in next page in all browser except

- MAC -Yoshemite - Safari
- IOS - IPHONE 6 Mobile- Safari

  Do I need to update the below code to work in Safari.

  ```
  string CookieName= "dsResponse";
  string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);    

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CookieName] != null)
  {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[CookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  }
  HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie(CookieName)
  {
      Value = json,
      HttpOnly = false,
      Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cookiesecond"]))
  });
  ```

Comment: How long is the string you tried to save in a cookie? Cookies have a limited space to save data.

Comment: But same thing working in others browser

Comment: How big is the size of your cookie ? Safari in particular requires to use slim cookies - 4093B per domain is a limit; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: is this a 3rd party cookie? Those are blocked by default in Safari

Answer (score 0):

1st: you are overwriting the cookie - not expiring it with this code.
The response object is sent once - with your "new" cookie.
If the cookie exists - just change its value and/or the content.
I would check your assumption on AppSettings["cookiesecond"]

Also try this:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("http_user_agent").IndexOf("Safari", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1 Then
    Me.Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"
```

It may be the browser caps not matching...

Answer (score 0):

There was some comma was coming in JSON data and its breaking at the time of deserilze the data.

```
var cookieValue = (json).Replace(";", "").Replace(",", "***");
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type.ToLower().Contains("safari"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", sessionName + "=" + cookieValue + "; path=/;");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default cookie not allowed for iOS safari browser. We have to enable cookies setting from iOS safari browser,

Solution :-
-we have implemented local storage(java script concept)to overcome the cookie problems in iOS safari browser.