# How to fix "Bad Request" error when I create big cookies in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am dealing with some data from my dataBase, on my PHP(html) page.
So before the Html code starts I put some PHP code, and I want to "live" *(edit note: probably "leave" or "give")* my html page some text data, so the js will deal with it.
I've created it like that:

```
<?php
/*some code.. */
setcookie("name","**BIG DATA**");
?>
<html>
<!--All the HTML code-->
</html>
```

Because the data in the cookie is big, it sends me the
"Bad Request" error page, and it blocks all my site. So I needed to delete all my cookies in my browser so it will continue to work.
I've tried to divide it to an array of cookies, so each cookie will be about 300 chars, but it doesn't help...

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: Why do you need big cookies? Store a session id, and store the data in a database / localStorage and sync sometimes...

Comment: I wood like you to expalin about that or let me see where can read about it.

Comment: Solution: don't have "big" cookie. And all problems magically disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply output into js directly e.g:

```
<script>

var fromserver="<?php
/*some code.. */
echo "**BIG DATA**";
?>";
```

And you may store it in localStorage if you want to:

```
if(fromServer){
 //store
localStorage.fromServer=fromServer;
}else{
 fromServer=localStorage.fromServer;
}

alert(fromServer);
```

It will behave like a never expiring cookie, but the memory limit is much higher.

```
</script>
```

Comment: the problem width outpot to the js directly, is that forstly it can make promlem if in the data I have ",' and some other text promlem (for eampel enter in the tex), secondly, it is un tidy code... you can't just put text in the HTML..

Comment: @user5460170 yes you could. Depends on the usecase.

Answer (score 0):

The 4K limit you read about is for the entire cookie, including name, value, expiry date etc. If you want to support most browsers, I suggest keeping the name under 4000 bytes, and the overall cookie size under 4093 bytes

Comment: Copy + Paste !== Answer

Comment: if you think its a duplicate, flag it as duplicate. That will help the OP more, as the answers in the original thread are better...

Comment: I do not se whole code, I don't know its duplicated or not ... maybe problem is with to big cookies, maybe not ... I don't understand peoples with XXX score in here ... You always have some problems but do not try to help ... I give You +1 score ;)