# Gonative.io app won't allow cookie update

Tags: php, cookies

I've wrapped a web application into a native format using gonative.io...the app is working great, but i can't update cookies.

The original cookie sets appropriately (and keeps the user logged in).  But if I try to update the cookie in the underlying web application, the cookie value remains unchanged.

Here are the parameters i'm using to set the cookie in php:

```
$sa = serialize($_SESSION);
$sab64 = base64_encode($sa);
$sab64E = $view->encryptString($sab64);
setcookie(APP_COOKIE_NAME, $sab64E, time() + 31536000, '/');
```

I have checked the [gonative documentation for keeping users logged in](https://support.gonative.io/help/how-can-i-keep-my-app-users-logged-in), but it only says "use persistent cookies".

How can I update the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie can't be over 4k.

I was able to reduce the cookie size by removing session parameters that don't need to be stored for reuse and can be regenerated upon a new login.  This appears to be related to the [maximum cookie size of safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key#answer-42315901) which is probably what gonative uses under the hood to do the browsing of the app that is wrapped.

Using a cookie that was only 2.3k, i was able to update the cookies in gonative.