# ASP.NET Core authentication/authorization with external OpenID Connect provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm learning authentication/authorization in ASP.NET Core and got confused by which components I should use in my scenario: I have an SPA frontend and an ASP.NET Core API backend. I'm using a third-party OpenID Connect provider (like Okta) that only supports Authorization Code Flow, so I believe only the backend should talk to this external provider. The external provider only handles authentication, not authorization. Our application needs role-based access control.

- Do we need Identity Server, considering authentication is already handled by the external OpenID Connect provider?
- Do we need ASP.NET Core Identity?
- How should we approach authorization in this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I assume by "Identity Server" you're referring to [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or maybe even [IdentityServer3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/))

> Do we need Identity Server, considering authentication is already handled by the external OpenID Connect provider?

No.

People use IdentityServer4 when they want to self-host their own IdP (and of course, you can still federate with Google, Facebook, Apple, etc when you self-host your own IdP too), but when you use an IdP-as-a-service like Okta or Azure AD then you don't need to run your own IdP.

> Do we need ASP.NET Core Identity?

No.

*ASP.NET Core Identity* is basically a utility-kit and time-saving library that <sub>(ostensibly...)</sub> makes it easier to crank-out the usual user-management features every traditional web-application needs: things like Registration, Password Resets, Automatic Lockout, Email+Phone verification, are all handled for you by ASP.NET Core Identity - including the user database via Entity Framework.

...but when you use an IdP-as-a-service then those same features (Registration, Forgot-password, etc) are supposed to be part of the service you're paying for (so you could either spend *tens of thousands of dollars* of dev-time building a self-hosted IdentityServer4 IdP - or you could skip all that and pay Okta merely *tens of dollars* per month instead. Guess which option your project budget manager wants to go with...

With ASP.NET Core Identity, or any self-hosted IdP where you have your own Users database tables, you'll need to query your own database to get user details (username, display-name, etc) <sub>(though normally you would store current-user-details in a structured security-token (JWT, SAML, `ClaimsIdentity`/`ClaimsPrincipal`, [`AuthenticationTicket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationticket), etc) when the user authenticates a new session so you avoid hitting your database on every request)</sub>...

... but when you use a non-local OIDC IdP (like Okta) those user details are stored and managed by Okta and also held by the client and then forwarded to you via the front-channel, or passed directly via the back-channel; those user details ("claims" in OIDC, known as "assertions" in SAML) are contained in 2 separate tokens: First, the `id_token` holds non-security-related user profile fields, like display-name and avatar image URI, while the `access_token` holds security claims and scopes (e.g. user role membership, account-is-locked-out status, etc). If your clients don't send you an `id_token` then you can always [use the IdP's user-info endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) to get the same data yourself (don't forget to cache it locally, otherwise it's even more expensive than hitting a local DB on every request).

SAML works very similar to OIDC, [just with its own terminology for almost identical concepts](https://www.onelogin.com/blog/real-difference-saml-oidc). As an aside, I'm far more familiar with OIDC and OAuth2 than SAML (with which I have zero experience with), but AFAIK SAML uses a single token for both identity-claims and security-<del>claims</del> assertions whereas OIDC splits it up into `id_token` and `access_token` (I might be wrong on this...)

> How should we approach authorization in this scenario?

[Use declarative Authorization Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which validate/authenticate based on specific user security claims in the `access_token` (**do not** use the `id_token` for authorization).

But while you can use the same C# Attributes for declarative authorization in your server-side code, be mindful that ASP.NET Web API clients and ASP.NET MVC browser visitors do things differently:

- In ASP.NET Web API, clients might be an user-interactive smartphone app or desktop command-line program (think like Azure PowerShell) - or it could be a headless background-worker or daemon process. Most importantly: all these clients share the ability to store secrets like Bearer Tokens *locally and securely* as they're programs running with some kind of read/write access to their local-disk.

  - <sub>(While JS SPA clients use ASP.NET Web API, they *don't* have the ability to store secrets, so they're a special case that I discuss later on).</sub>
  - These clients all send their `access_token` in the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer 3q2+7w==` request header, and ASP.NET Core's built-in JWT authX features will compare the claims in the `access_token` with your declared policies and use that to accept or reject the HTTP request.
- Whereas ASP.NET MVC clients are all web-browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc) which use traditional HTTP cookie-based authX + sessions.

  - Browser clients have their `access_token` (and optionally their `id_token`) stored *verbatim* inside their ASP.NET security cookie - or the ASP.NET security cookie stores some short reference to a persisted token cached server-side to prevent cookie bloat.

    - This security cookie is symmetrically encrypted by your web-application and marked HTTP-only, so even hostile injected scripts (XSS, etc) in a browser-page cannot access and read those token strings.
    - **Caution**: because `access_token` and `id_token` blobs can be quite large (easily multiple kilobytes) [you'll hit browsers' cookie length limits (4096 bytes?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key), so many web-applications just store all tokens privately (in Redis or memcached or something) and merely store *a reference* to the cached tokens.
- When it comes to JS SPAs (Angular, etc) things are *complicated*: the client is ostensibly a user's web-browser (well, it's actually JavaScript code in the browser) and so it will make `fetch`-based requests in the background (instead of browser foreground "top level" Document requests) using an `access_token` in the `Authorization` header instead of using cookies (which wouldn't be accessible to scripts anyway, due to it being HTTP-only and encrypted, assuming the even were in the ASP.NET security cookie in the first place) - but because JavaScript clients simply do not have any way of securely storing secrets locally (`window.localStorage` is not private), so SPAs had their own separate OIDC flow: the Implicit Flow, but it's basically insecure - that, combined with browsers' disabling cross-origin cookies and other techniques that OIDC's Front Channel relies on basically means that SPAs now should *not* make their own `fetch` HTTP requests to external RPs (i.e. the backend ASP.NET Web API service for an SPA front-end) but should instead be served from a simple ASP.NET MVC which proxies requests to external RPs, and so the SPA actually uses Cookies, not Bearer Tokens - and means that [the somewhat nice idea of hosting an SPA in static AWS S3 or Azure Blob storage is now dead](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/).

So if you're planning on building an SPA, you *really* should [give that
LeastPrivilege.com article a very good read](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/) so you understand how the browser landscape is changing (Dominick Baier is one of IdentityServer's creators and maintainers).

---

I will say that properly grokking OIDC is *hard* - I built a self-hosted IdP using IdentityServer4 and while I got something-out-the-door after a few months it still easily took me over a year to truly understand what was actually going on.

Comment: "Use declarative Authorization Policies which validate/authenticate based on specific user security claims in the access_token" -- is there a framework (maybe part of ASP.NET Core) you'd use to manage user permission information, or is it usually just implemented manually?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Please clarify what you mean by "manage user permission information" - are you asking about a webpage where you can add/edit users' details? If so, that's exactly what Okta is for.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, the particular OIDC provider we use doesn't provide any authorization functionalities at all; they only do authentication. So I assume we need to store the user/group/role information in house, say using EF Core. I wanted to ask if there is any framework that makes this part of the system easier.

Comment: _"the particular OIDC provider we use doesn't provide any authorization functionalities at all"_ - uhhh, that doesn't sound right to me. Exactly what Okta products/services are you using? [Okta has documentation on how you can assign role-memberships to users](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/role-assignment/), for example.... and [you can add custom claims by following this article](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-returned-from-okta/main/) - all your ASP.NET Core authorization policies need to do is inspect those claims in the received tokens.

Comment: Oh we are not using Okta, I just mentioned Okta as an example. It's a foreign provider that we need to use for regulatory reason.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Can you share any details about who or what it is?

Comment: It's Alibaba Cloud's IDaaS.

Comment: Another question: Do the SPA issues (mentioned in the LeastPrivilege.com article) still apply when the SPA and the API backend share the same domain? In this case wouldn't secure HTTP cookies be enough?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Alibaba Cloud IAM/IDaaS stores your users' details and you can set claims for each user through their service - your ASP.NET authorization policies will then perform authorization based on those claims. (It looks like their IDaaS is still in Beta though...)