# securecookie: the value is too long when using sessions.NewFilesystemStore

Tags: go, session-cookies

I am building an app that uses sessions to store user data. For that I use the gorilla/sessions package.

The problem I encounter is that the user data I would like to store is getting bigger and bigger as the application grows.

At some point, i get that error while saving the session : `securecookie: the value is too long`

Here is how I build my storage :

```golang
sessions.NewFilesystemStore("", []byte("abcdef"))
```

How should I do to store large session data ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is heritage from the [4Kb maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key) of a browser cookie. Of course the filesystem store and probably any other store that is not the cookie store can hold large(r) session data. However, it [defaults](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go#L166) to 4Kb for some reason. To change it just do something like:

```
fs := sessions.NewFilesystemStore("", []byte("mysecretkey"))
fs.MaxLength(8192) // 8Kb is now maximum size of the session
```