# Save Javascript result to a cookie

Tags: javascript

I am using BotD for bot detection, and trying to figure out how to save the result into a cookie.

(I am sure this is simple, but im still trying to learn JS and stuck here)

Initial code:

```
<script>
    // Initialize an agent at application startup, once per page/app.
    const botdPromise = import('https://openfpcdn.io/botd/v1').then((Botd) => Botd.load())
    // Get detection results when you need them.
    botdPromise
        .then((botd) => botd.detect())
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
</script>
```

I tried:

```
<script>
    // Initialize an agent at application startup, once per page/app.
    const botdPromise = import('https://openfpcdn.io/botd/v1').then((Botd) => Botd.load())
    // Get detection results when you need them.
    botdPromise
        .then((botd) => botd.detect())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            document.cookie ="botd="+result+"; path=/; secure; SameSite=strict";  
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
</script>
```

It prints correctly on console with "Object { bot: false }", but the cookie just says [object Object]

Any help with an example of how to get it to work would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: cookies store text values, an Object is not text -JavaScript Object Notation is text notation for simple objects

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can only store string values. What you can do is to parse the object result you get into string by using `JSON.stringfy` method, and then store the string into cookies.

Example:

```js
const object = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "boy",
  c: "cat",
  d: "dog",
  e: "eleplant",
  f: "fox",
  g: "goat",
  h: "hen",
  i: "iguana"
}

console.log(typeof object);
console.log(object);
//Parse Object to String
const string = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(typeof string);
console.log(string);
//From here, store the string into cookies
```

Tips: Cookies does have a [size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604212/9499523). Thus, if the object is too complex/big, then it might not be able to store with cookies after stringify. You might need to look for other approach like localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line :

```
document.cookie ="botd="+result+"; path=/; secure; SameSite=strict";
```

to :

```
document.cookie ="botd="+JSON.stringify(result)+"; path=/; secure; SameSite=strict";
```

because `document.cookie` only accepts `String` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie)). So that JSON should be converted into String with `JSON.stringify` method