# Not all cookie saved from one page

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a long text that needs to be saved in cookies. I break it down by the number of characters and try to save it into cookies cyclically, but only the last one is saved. Below is an example of code that should do this.

To save cookies:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$token = generateRandomString(8851);
$name = 'ck';
$exp = 3600;
$domain = '.example.local';

if(strlen($token) > 4096) {
    $values = str_split($token, 4095);
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        setcookie(
            name: $name . '_' . $key,
            value: $value,
            expires_or_options: time() + $exp,
            domain: $domain
        );
    }
} else {
    setcookie(
        name: $name,
        value: $token,
        expires_or_options: time() + $exp,
        domain: $domain
    );
}
```

For view cookies:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: Have you checked the set-cookie header in the response? What's the value?

Comment: @shingo I have 3 set-cookie headers in response and everything is correct there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum size of a web browser's cookie's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)

Comment: Is the code in your question not just an "example", but did you actually _run and test it_ as you published it here?

Comment: If you need long term data use a) localStorage if only the browser needs access (javascript) or b) use a server side database. There should be no need to transfer large data on every request.

Comment: would suspect that the domain is the cause of trouble. leading dot means that the cookie is shared for all subdomains but the top domain does not have access to these cookies, so in case you are testing it from top domain then this is it

Comment: @Kazz Then why was the last cookie written and I see it?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I need to transfer long text from PHP to JS. JS on the main domain, PHP on the subdomain

Comment: @KIKOSoftware For what purpose are you interested? I described the problem and attached the code that does not solve it. The question is why the code behaves this way.

Comment: Then you should provide an REST-API for that in PHP. Cookies are the wrong way. In JS you can pull the data via fetch API.

Comment: oh that was how it worked, it is no longer the case, sorry ignore my comment

Comment: Instead of evading the question, you could simple answer it. Did, or did you not, test the exact code that is present in your question? The reason I want to know is that I don't immediately see an error, so the only way to find an error is to actually test it, but that would be utterly pointless if you haven't done that yourself.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Of course I checked. I asked a question and described in detail what was happening...

Comment: OK, I tested your code on my server, and I found that I couldn't generate cookies with a total size more than roughly 4000 bytes. That's for all the cookies, including name, value, expiry date. That seems to be a server problem however, not a browser problem. I never need more than a 100 bytes or so, so it's not a problem for me. That being said, cookies are not the right way to transfer data from PHP to JS. If you want data from PHP in JS, just ask for it in JS, for instance with [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).